Containerised Appium Test automation
I am using an Appium service to automate a flutter application on Android. I was able to connect to my host's ADB and install Appium Settings and the flutter application. But I was not able to connect to AndroidUiautomator2Driver as shown in the logs below:
[ADB] Running '/usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s RR8W802EFNN install -r -g /home/myuser/app-debug.apk'
[ADB] The installation of 'app-debug.apk' took 7979ms
[ADB] Install command stdout: Performing Streamed Install
[ADB] Success
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@9de5 (9d152cd0)] Performing shallow cleanup of automation leftovers
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@9de5 (9d152cd0)] No obsolete sessions have been detected (connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8200)
[ADB] Running '/usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s RR8W802EFNN shell am force-stop io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test'
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@9de5 (9d152cd0)] Starting UIAutomator2 server 5.12.16
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@9de5 (9d152cd0)] Using UIAutomator2 server from '/home/myuser/.appium/node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-driver/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-server/apks/appium-uiautomator2-server-v5.12.16.apk' and test from '/home/myuser/.appium/node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-driver/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-server/apks/appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk'
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@9de5 (9d152cd0)] Waiting up to 30000ms for UiAutomator2 to be online...
[ADB] Creating ADB subprocess with args: ["-P","5037","-s","RR8W802EFNN","shell","am","instrument","-w","-e","disableAnalytics","true","io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"]
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@9de5 (9d152cd0)] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@9de5 (9d152cd0)] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/status] with no body
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@9de5 (9d152cd0)] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8200
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@9de5 (9d152cd0)] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@9de5 (9d152cd0)] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/status] with no body
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@9de5 (9d152cd0)] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8200

And this is how I configure the environment in my Dockerfile:
RUN apt-get update  \
    && yes | apt-get install -y maven  \
    && yes | apt-get install usbutils \
    && apt install wget \
    && yes | apt-get install android-sdk \
    && yes | apt-get install android-tools-adb \
    && apt clean  \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


ENV ANDROID_HOME "/usr/lib/android-sdk"
ENV ANDROID_SDK_ROOT $ANDROID_HOME
ENV PATH $PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platforms:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools
ENV ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_ADDRESS "host.docker.internal"


RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash myuser \
    && usermod -aG root myuser

USER myuser

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-c"]

RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash \
    && source $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh \
    && nvm install v16.18.1 \
    && npm install -g appium@latest \
    && appium driver install uiautomator2  \
    && appium driver install xcuitest  \
    && appium driver install --source=npm appium-flutter-driver  \
    && appium plugin install relaxed-caps  \
    && appium plugin install execute-driver \
    && appium plugin install --source=npm appium-wait-plugin

And this is how my compose.yml look like:
services:
  service:
    image: image
    network_mode: host
    hostname: localhost
    volumes:
      - /Users/.m2:/home/myuser/.m2

I even tried to curl to http://127.0.0.1:8200 on the container, and was Connection refused. But when I curl from my laptop it works fine. I do not understand what am I doing wrong. Since the network_mode is set to host, the container should be able to connect to any localhost port no? How can I make this work?

As I see it's an issue on Mac https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1031

The issue you are experiencing is probably a docker network issue.
Try updating your dockerfile :
FROM openjdk:11-jdk-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    wget curl unzip android-tools-adb \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV ANDROID_HOME /opt/android-sdk
ENV PATH ${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools

RUN mkdir -p ${ANDROID_HOME} && cd ${ANDROID_HOME} \
    && wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-7583922_latest.zip \
    && unzip commandlinetools-linux-7583922_latest.zip \
    && rm commandlinetools-linux-7583922_latest.zip \
    && yes | sdkmanager --licenses \
    && sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-30" "build-tools;30.0.3"

RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash \
    && . $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh \
    && nvm install 16.18.1 \
    && npm install -g appium@latest \
    && appium driver install uiautomator2 flutter \
    && appium plugin install relaxed-caps execute-driver appium-wait-plugin

CMD ["appium", "--allow-insecure", "chromedriver_autodownload"]

And your docker compose :
version: '3'
services:
  appium:
    build: .
    privileged: true
    network_mode: host
    environment:
      - ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_ADDRESS=host.docker.internal
    volumes:
      - /dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb
      - ~/.m2:/home/appuser/.m2
    ports:
      - "4723:4723"

Ensure your device is connected and visible in ADBm then build and run the docker compose to see if the issue is resolved

I was not able to build the docker image. "4.728 /bin/sh: 1: sdkmanager: not found". I modified the first apt-get to install android-sdk but I still get the same error. sdkmanager: not found

Check the location of the ANDROID_HOME var, try changing for $HOME/Android/Sdk
